# How can I add years to multiple drop downs by name, using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Here's a jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qHSWK/247/ and code I found, but originally it was by id. I have multiple drop downs that will have the same content, so it would be better to do them all at once by name. Not great with javascript, but I thought it would work this way. What's wrong here?

```
<form id="someform">
<select name="year"></select>
</form>

var myselect = document.getElementsByName("year"),
startYear = new Date().getFullYear()
count = 5;

(function(select, val, count) {
 do {
select.add(new Option(val++, count--), null);
} while (count);
})(myselect, startYear, count);
```

Final with multiple drop downs:

```
var myselect = document.getElementsByName("year"),
startYear = new Date().getFullYear()
count = 45;

for (var n = 0; n<5;n++){ 
(function(select, val, count) {
do {
select.add(new Option(val--, count--), null);

} while (count);
})(myselect[n], startYear, count);


}
```

Comment: Your `myselect` is a collection of elements. Use `myselect[0]` to access first select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply this to multiple `select` elements like in the below example.

```js
var myselect = document.querySelectorAll("[name=year],[name=year1],[name=year2]"),
    startYear = new Date().getFullYear(),
    count = 5;
for(i=0;i<myselect.length;i++) {
(function(select, val, count) {
  do {
    select.add(new Option(val++, count--), null);
  } while (count);
})(myselect[i], startYear, count);
}
```

```html
<form id="someform">
  <select name="year"></select>
  <select name="year1"></select>
  <select name="year2"></select>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you show the example with `multiple dropdowns`, as Nick asked?

Comment: @skobaljic do you see multiple dropdowns in OP's code?

Comment: Well that is the end goal, I was just trying to get the first step out of the way ..

Comment: @skobaljic yes i saw it in the first place and thought to give an example for one `select` element as in OP's example but since you are right and this has to be done for multiple i updated my answer.

Comment: Just trying to help, +1

Answer (score 2):

getElementsByName returns a NodeList, not a single element. That's why you'll need to add the needed index " **[0]** " to the "select" var inside the loop. This way:

```
select[0].add(new Option(val++, count--), null);
```